# Error when trying to get data with asynchronous functions (web scraping)

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, async-await, aiohttp

I want to improve my code, changing the synchronous functions to asynchronous for a faster data extraction speed, but every time I run the program, I get the Print("Error").

```
async def soup(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    return soup


async def title_bs4(html, tag, classes):
    soup = await soup(html)
    title = soup.findAll(tag, attrs={"class": classes})
    title = [i.text for i in title]
    return title


async def url_bs4(html, tag, classes):
    soup = await soup(html)
    url = soup.findAll(tag, attrs={"class": classes})
    url = [i.text for i in url]
    return url


async def price_xpath(html):
    soup = await soup(html)
    dom = etree.HTML(str(soup))
    price = dom.xpath('//li[@class="ui-search-layout__item shops__layout-item"]//div[@class="ui-search-result__content-columns shops__content-columns"]/div[@class="ui-search-result__content-column ui-search-result__content-column--left shops__content-columns-left"]/div[1]/div//div[@class="ui-search-price__second-line shops__price-second-line"]//span[@class="price-tag-amount"]/span[2]')
    price = [i.text.replace('.', '') for i in price]
    return price


async def page_number_bs4(html, tag, classes):
    soup = await soup(html)
    page_number = soup.find(tag, attrs={"class": classes}).text
    page_number = int(page_number)
    return page_number


async def number_of_pages_bs4(html, tag, classes):
    soup = await soup(html)
    number_of_pages = soup.find(tag, attrs={"class": classes}).text
    number_of_pages = int(number_of_pages.split(" ")[1])
    return number_of_pages


async def next_xpath(html):
    soup = await soup(html)
    dom = etree.HTML(str(soup))
    next = dom.xpath(
        '//div[@class="ui-search-pagination shops__pagination-content"]/ul/li[contains(@class,"--next")]/a')[0].get('href')
    return next


async def main(product):
    web = "Mercado libre"
    list_titles = []
    list_urls = []
    list_prices = []
    next = 'https://listado.mercadolibre.com.co/' + str(product)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(next) as response:
            while True:
                try:
                    title = await title_bs4(response, 'h2', 'ui-search-item__title shops__item-title')
                    list_titles.extend(title)
                    url = await url_bs4(response, 'a', 'ui-search-item__group__element shops__items-group-details ui-search-link')
                    list_titles.extend(url)
                    price = await price_xpath(response)
                    list_titles.extend(price)
                    page_number = await page_number_bs4(response, 'span', 'andes-pagination__link')
                    number_of_pages = await number_of_pages_bs4(response, 'li', 'andes-pagination__page-count')
                except:
                    print("Error")
                    break
                if page_number == number_of_pages:
                    break
                next = await next_xpath(response)
            df = pd.DataFrame({"shop": web, "titles": list_titles,
                               "links": list_urls, "prices": list_prices})
            df.prices = df.prices.map(
                lambda x: float(re.search(r"\d+", x).group(0)))
            df.to_json("templates/product.json", orient='records')
            return df

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
try:
    asyncio.run(main('samsung'))
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    pass
```

My synchronous functions work very well but are very slow when it comes to wanting to extract data from the paginations.

I want to find the solution when running the program or if there is another better alternative to what I am looking for above.

Comment: Show the stack trace.

Comment: `Exception has occurred: UnboundLocalError
local variable 'soup' referenced before assignment
  File "C:\Users\BangGod\Desktop\YTorres\prueba.py", line 16, in title_bs4
    soup = await soup(html)
  File "C:\Users\BangGod\Desktop\YTorres\prueba.py", line 69, in main
    title = await title_bs4(response, 'h2', 'ui-search-item__title shops__item-title')
  File "C:\Users\BangGod\Desktop\YTorres\prueba.py", line 93, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main('samsung'))
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'soup' referenced before assignment`

Comment: Edit your question to add the properly formatted stack trace.